# Using a variable for Element name in Core Data Predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I am trying to write a method which tries to retrieve an object based on a predicate using a variable (as part of a NSXMLParser). The code looks like this:

I have these variables defined in the class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *model;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *element;
```

Now in the method, I set up the request like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.model inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
```

Now the challenge - what I **want** to be able to do is:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", self.element,string]];
```

But that does not return any results. After some mucking around, I notice that this **does** work:

```
 if ( [self.element isEqualToString:@"name"] ) {
     [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", string]];
 }
```

This tells me that my `self.element` is set correctly (I think?) but that the predicate doesn't like the left hand side of the expression being a variable.

I also tried:

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%s == %@", [self.element UTF8String],string]];
```

... just to see if perhaps it preferred a string. I couldn't make that work either.

Is what I am attempting even possible? I've read as much as I can of the Core Data documentation and I can't find any sample code which does it this way, but I also didn't find anything to say it wasn't possible.

EDIT:
and now the working code:

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", self.element,string]];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you haven't done before, read the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1) and you can find everything about predicates.

Now, if I've understood correctly, you want to create a predicate between two string but the first isn't a defined string but it can change.
I haven't used them before but I believe you can solve your problem by using a predicate with dynamic property names.

Here from the documentation:

> **Dynamic Property Names**
>   Because string variables are surrounded by
>   quotation marks when they are substituted into a format string using
>   `%@`, you cannot use `%@` to specify a dynamic property name—as
>   illustrated in the following example.
>
> ```
> NSString *attributeName = @"firstName";  
> NSString *attributeValue = @"Adam";  
> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ like %@", attributeName, attributeValue];
> ```
>
> The predicate format string in this case evaluates to "firstName" like "Adam".
>
> If you want to specify a dynamic property name, you use `%K` in the
>   format string, as shown in the following fragment.
>
> ```
> predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", attributeName, attributeValue];
> ```
>
> The predicate format string in this case evaluates to firstName like "Adam" (note that there are no
>   quotation marks around firstName).

More info can be found also here: [Predicate Format String Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW4).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. The specific piece of information that makes my code work is the %K variable which treats the argument as a key rather than a value. Now working =)

Comment: you're welcome :) Core Data and Predicates are awesome technologies and you can do everything with them...